# Having problems with complex query (Laravel Eloquent)

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent

It's been a long time :D

Lately, I've been trying to develop a website and I don't seem to get a solution. It's been 3 weeks and I can't make it yet. **I'm not using models because I still don't understand them as much as I'd like, and maybe things like hasmany or belongsto would make a difference, but i don't know how to use them**

---

This is the query:

```
$threads = DB::table('threads')
    ->join('users as author', 'author.id', '=', 'threads.user_id')
    ->join('replies', 'replies.thread_id', '=', 'threads.id')
    ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'threads.category_id')
    ->join('users as users', 'users.id', '=', 'replies.user_id')
    ->select('threads.id as thread_id','threads.category_id as thread_category','threads.title as thread_title', 'replies.body as thread_first_message', 'author.name as thread_author', 'author.id as author_id', 'replies.created_at as last_reply_date', 'users.name as last_reply_user', 'users.id as lru_id', 'threads.visits', 'threads.hd', 'threads.18', 'threads.prv', DB::raw('(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM replies WHERE thread_id = threads.id) as count_replies'))
    ->where('replies.created_at', '=', DB::raw('(SELECT max(created_at) FROM replies)'));
```

I need to get multiple data from 3 tables.

I'm gonna explain what every column is about:

**`thread_id`**: field (id) from table 'threads'

**`thread_category`**: field (category_id) from 'threads' and foreign key from table 'categories' (id)

**`thread_title`**: field (title) from 'threads'

**`thread_first_message`**: **first** field (body) from table 'replies' where thread_id = (**`thread_id`**)

**`thread_author`**: field (user_id) from 'threads' and foregin key from table 'users' (id)

**`author_id`**: field (id) from 'users' that wrote the first message

**`last_reply_date`**: field (created_at) from 'replies' where 'replies.id' = (**`thread_id`**)

**`last_reply_users`**: field (name) from 'users' that wrote that last message in (**`thread_id`**)

**`lru_id`**: field (id) from 'users' from 'users' that wrote that last message in (**`thread_id`**)

**`visits`**: field (visits) from table 'threads'

**`hd, prv, 18`**: boolean fields (they dont matter here, maybe in a future) from table 'threads'

**`count_replies`**: SUM of all the replies from where thread_id = (**`thread_id`**)

---

Database looks like this by the moment:

[image]

---

My problem is that I have 2 records in the database, so 2 divs should show in the page, but only shows one:

The result i'm getting:

[image]

The result I need:

[image]

As the threads table has 2 records:

[image]

**Can u guys send me some help? Thank you in advance**

**EDIT**: I made it to here so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t.id), t.category_id, t.title, r1.body, u1.name as author, u1.id, r2.created_at, u2.id as last_author_id, u2.name as last_author, t.visits, COUNT(DISTINCT(r3.id)) from threads t, replies r1, replies r2, replies r3, users u1, users u2 where r1.thread_id = t.id and u1.id = t.user_id and r2.thread_id = t.id and r2.user_id = u2.id and r3.thread_id = t.id group by t.id
```

It retrieves this:

[image]

I don't know how to convert that into a Eloquent Query or if is it optimal

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql.

Comment: I am just getting 1 result, but there would be 2 as my db has 2 thread records

Comment: There are no 'records' here. Only pictures of ERDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do this the Laravel way.

First of all, you should create the Models. Create the directory app/Models and put those files in there:

Thread.php:

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Thread extends Model {

  public function author() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id')
  }

  public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id')
  }

  public function replies() {
    return $this->hasMany(Reply::class, 'thread_id');
  }
}
```

User.php:

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model {

  public function threads() {
    return $this->hasMany(Thread::class, 'user_id')
  }

  public function replies() {
    return $this->hasMany(Reply::class, 'user_id')
  }

  public function votes() {
    return $this->hasMany(Vote::class, 'user_id')
  }
}
```

Reply.php

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Reply extends Model {

  public function thread() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Thread::class, 'thread_id')
  }

  public function author() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id')
  }

  public function votes() {
    return $this->hasMany(Vote::class, 'reply_id')
  }
}
```

Category.php

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model {

  public function threads() {
    return $this->hasMany(Thread::class, 'category_id')
  }
}
```

Vote.php

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Vote extends Model {

  public function author() {
    return $this->belogsTo(User::class, 'user_id')
  }

  public function reply() {
    return $this->belogsTo(Reply::class, 'reply_id')
  }
}
```

Now, given a Thread, you can easily get the results you need

```
// last 10 threads
$threads = Thread::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
   ->with('category')->limit(10)->get();

// You can loop on the blade template and display the informations you need
foreach($threads as $thread) {
  $thread->category->id; // The thread category ID
  $thread->category->name; // The thread category name

  $lastReply = $thread->replies()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first(); // The last reply on the thread
  $lastReply->created_at; // Date of the latest reply
  $lastReply->author->name; // Name of the user that created the last reply

  $thread->visits; // The number of visits on the thread
  $repliesCount = $thread->replies()->count(); // Number of replies on the thread
}
```

Comment: Your answer was very helpful!!! Thank you so much!!! Now I get to understand better about Models and their importance on the queries. Now I just need to make some joins so I get all the remaining data and we're good to go. Thank you so much!!!!!